# How to class c# function in asp classic

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I need to call c# function is asp classic. I have created a class in c#  and try to create object and access methods in asp classic.

Is any one knows how to do this?

Comment: @CodeCaster - while I agree that the answer is there, you first need to know that you need something like "COM interop" to call a .Net class from ASP classic. So I don't think this qualifies as "duplicate".

Comment: @Hans you're right in that the answer to this question is _"You can use COM interop"_, and that answer can link to that question. Though I find it clearer to just directly link to it as duplicate. I don't find the _question_ duplicate per se, but the question _is answered in that question_. :)